# Autoconfiguration of Mail in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-mail-app

Simply, is it possible to automatically configure the ModernUI Mail application for domain users?

I would imagine this is possible through some ini, registry, or script but I've not been able to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it uses the Microsoft Autodiscovery method to obtain mail settings. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc433481(v=EXCHG.80).aspx for details on this.